# annotate command not working, added it to my gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

My gem file looks like:

```
 group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
 end
```

I ran '`bundle install`' and it installed the annotate-models bundle.

If I type: `annotate` I get a command not found error.

If I type: `bundle show annotate` I get a 'could not find gem annotate in the current bundle.

If I type bundle show annotate-models it says it installed in:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/annotate-models-1.0.4
```

typing:

```
annotate-models
```

doesn't work either.

I'm following along in railstutorial.org and got stuck at this point.

Comment: Bundler can be used in Rails 2.x too, but I'm guessing too it is Rails3. To the OP: Care to share?

Comment: Yes I am using Rails 3.0, it doesn't work in 3.0?

Comment: I'm going through the tutorial, as well. After success install according to the accepted answer here, I get this error on bundle install: "Could not find gem 'annotate-models (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile." - I have a line in my Gemfile for gem 'annotate-models' - anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 34):

Edit: Better version (using Bundler to install it only for the current project)

1. Add `gem 'annotate'` to Gemfile
2. Run `$ bundle install`
3. Run `$ bundle exec annotate`

Edit2: Seems you have to explicitly specify annotate version for now, so in Gemfile put `gem 'annotate', '2.4.1.beta1'` (which is a prereleased beta gem that works with the latest version of activerecord as opposed to specifying the github repo directly)

Edit3: 2.5.0 final is out now, so hopefully no need to force a beta version any more, just getting the latest should work!

Old version (with installing the gem on a system level too):

If running Rails 3 the drill is:

1. Run `$ sudo gem install annotate`
2. Add `gem 'annotate'` to Gemfile
3. Run `$ bundle install`
4. Run `$ annotate`
5. Be happy :)

Comment: +1 This worked for me on Mac OS X 10.6 with ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3. I think 'sudo' is the key to make it work for Mac OS.

Comment: I had to do "rvm gem install annotate"

Comment: Ok, but can you explain why? Does this mean the rails 3 version of the annotate-models gem is not in rubygems.org source so we need to install it via the gem tool? Just curious... (edit: nevermind, the gem is obviously now named annotate instead of annotate-models!)

Comment: I'm still getting this error.  rails 3.1.3 on a Mac.  It shows I have annotate 2.4 installed (when doing gem list -d annotate).

Answer (score 10):

You should run the command inside your bundled environment with:

```
$ bundle exec annotate
```

Check out the [man page](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

The most voted answer didn't fully work for me, as I was getting and additional error when follow the proposed solution:

```
undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I'm including below what worked for me (I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.3 under Ubuntu 11.10):

1. Install annotate

   ```
   $ gem install annotate
   ```
2. Modify Gemfile adding the following line

   ```
   gem 'annotate', 
       :git => 'git://github.com/jeremyolliver/annotate_models.git', 
       :branch => 'rake_compatibility'
   ```
3. Install bundle

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```
4. Now you can use annotate as follows:

   ```
   $ bundle exec annotate
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to this, but I was having this problem doing the rails tutorial, but by adding the gems bin path to the PATH env variable I was able to fix it. (Just like gertas said a few posts above)

First in the command prompt:

```
gem list -d annotate
```

and you'll get a result that says something like

> : annotate-models (1.0.4)
>
> Author: Dave Thomas
>
> Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/annotate-models
>
> Homepage: h'ttp://annotate-models.rubyforge.org
>
> Installed at: C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

the key line is:

Installed at: C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

So in this case add a /bin to that path, For example I used: C:\ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin is what you want to add to your PATH environment variable.

To change your PATH environment variable on Vista do the following go to: control panel >> system >> advanced system settings(link on the left). Once the box opens up,click the *Advanced* tab and then the *Environment variables* button. Then on the system variables find the PATH variable and click the *Edit* button. Since paths are separated by semi-colons, add

`;C:\ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin`

At the end of the variable value field.

It should look like 
`some/path;some_other_path;C:\ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin` 
when you finish

Save it, and close and reopen the command prompt. annotate and rspec started to work for me after that. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

For me the answer was this one:
http://news.railstutorial.org/model-annotation

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
```

instead of

```
gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
```

It looks like the gem name was changed at RubyGems.org.

Answer (score 0):

I think your PATH env variable lacks path to gems bin directory.
I guess it should be: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for Rails 4, add gem in your gem file gem "annotate", "~> 2.5.0" and run following command

```
rails g annotate_models:install
```

instead of

```
rails g annotate:install
```

Then run following command to add schema information after model class

```
bundle exec annotate -p after
```

or can use following for before

```
 bundle exec annotate -p before
```

Answer (score 0):

If  `bundle exec annotate` doesn't work, try:

```bash
rake annotate_models
```